# Retrieved data from Localstorage not fresh

Tags: reactjs, redux, dispatch

I am pushing data into my local storage using dispatch then I history push to **/cart** to go further

But the data isn't what've just dispatched, not until I've forced refreshed my page.

How can I always have the most fresh localStorage data with a history.push workflow ?

```
const submitHandler = (e) => {
    dispatch(
      saveBeneficiaireProfile({
        firstname,
        identifiant,
        adultCount,
        childCount,
        babyCount,
      })
    );
    props.history.push("/cart");
  };
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get fresh data using useEffect hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
    
    const profile = localStorage.getBeneficiaireProfile();
    //Also you can save data to state variable and use anywhere
    
  }, []);//this only initialize once
```

**Retrieve data to local storage**

```
getBeneficiaireProfile = ()=>{
    //Get data from local store and return
}
```